# color ProgressBar in Thread

Tags: c#

I want change the color of my ProgressBar in a thread.I use this code.

```
    public static class ModifyProgressBarColor
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr w, IntPtr l);
    public static void SetState(this ProgressBar pBar, int state)
    {
        SendMessage(pBar.Handle, 1040, (IntPtr)state, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

What changes should I make in the code?
bellow code is in the tread.

```
ModifyProgressBarColor.SetState(progressBar1, 2);
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing exactly?

Comment: Why a Message? What's wrong with `pBar.ForeColor =Color.Green;` ?

Comment: I want change the color of progressbar in a thread.but I have this error

Comment: I want change the color of progressbar in a thread.but I have this error :    cross-thread operation not valid: control  'progressbar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Answer (score 1):

Change your `SetState()` method so it uses `Invoke()` like this:

```
public static void SetState(this ProgressBar pBar, int state)
{
    pBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        SendMessage(pBar.Handle, 1040, (IntPtr)state, IntPtr.Zero);
    });        
}
```

This will make the change occur on the same UI thread that owns the ProgressBar, getting rid of the error message.

Comment: Yes, the Invoke is the solution, the SendMessage can go.